# Is it possible to add a key attribute after a React component is instantiated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This example is contrived, but it gets at what I need to do.

Say I have an existing component like this:

```
var c1 = React.DOM.p( {} );
```

And later I need to use this component in the context of an array, like this:

```
var container = React.DOM.div( {}, [ c1, c2 ] );
```

This will create a div with child components of `c1` and `c2`, but React complains about the lack of a key attribute on the items in the array passed to the div function.

Is it possible to first add a key to the already-existing `c1` component prior to passing it to the container? I do realize it could be set when `c1` is first created, but I need to do it afterwards.

I'm looking through the React methods and addons and not seeing anything that addresses this case.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, after re-reading the [documentation here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children), I noticed this line:

> You can also key children by passing an object. The object keys will be used as key for each value.

So, rather than passing in an array above, I can do something like this instead:

```
var p = React.DOM.p( {} ),
    contentObject = {
        component1: p,
        component2: somethingElse
    },
    container = React.DOM.div( {}, contentObject );
```

And react will interpret the object parameters as the keys for those components.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to suppress the warning/make it explicit, you can use a utility function:

```
function keyByIndex(xs){
  var obj = {};
  for (var i=0; i<xs.length; i++) obj["k"+i] = xs[i];
  return obj;
}
```

```
render: function(){
  var array = [div(null, "hello"), div(null, "world")];
  return div(null, keyByIndex(array));
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/bivizosoza/3/edit?js,output)

---

Also keep in mind these are equivalent:

```
React.DOM.div({}, c1, c2)
React.DOM.div({}, {a: c1, b: c2})
React.DOM.div({}, keyByIndex([c1, c2]))
```